# When is the Lebesgue integral continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\sigma: [ 0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a Borel-measurable, nonnegative, extended-real valued function, when is the Lebesgue integral $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(u) du$ a continuous function of t? Thanks!

Comment: Note that any antiderivative of a locally integrable function is not merely continuous, but also absolutely continuous.

Comment: Do we know something else, like $\sigma\in L^1_{loc}[0,\infty)$ or something?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is locally integrable, then the function is in fact differentiable a.e. (ie, the Lebesgue points).

Comment: Notice that $\sigma$ is nondecreasing, which implies that the set $\{t: \sigma(t)<\infty \}$ is an interval. In this interval (possibly empty) you have local integrability, hence local absolute continuity of the antiderivative. Outside of it, the antiderivative is $\equiv \infty$.

Comment: @Leonid: No assumption on the variations of $\sigma$.

Comment: @did Sorry, I meant the unnamed antiderivative of $\sigma$.

Comment: @Leonid: Yep, that was my guess... :-)

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Thank you! That is the answer I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my answer-comment had a couple of typos and did not cover all bases, I'm posting an actual answer in the answer box (what a novel idea!).

Let $F(t)=\int_0^{t}\sigma(u)\,du$, which is a well-defined function taking values in $[0,\infty]$. Since $\sigma\ge 0$, $F$ is nondecreasing, which implies that the set $I=\{t:F(t)<\infty\}$ is an interval. On this (possibly empty) interval $\sigma$ is locally integrable, and therefore $F$ is locally absolute continuous. Outside of the interval $F\equiv +\infty$.

The question remains: what happens at right endpoint of $I$ when this endpoint is finite? Here a discontinuity may occur, e.g., if $\sigma\equiv \infty$ or $\sigma=\infty \chi_{[1,\infty)}$ or, to give a finite example, $\sigma(u)=(u-1)^{-1}\chi_{(1,\infty)}$. Denoting the right endpoint of $I$ by $b$, we can formulate the criterion for continuity at $b$ (hence on the entire line) as $\int_0^b \sigma(u)\,du=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is very clear.